# Accounting for pressure energy in Euler turbine/pump equation

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pumps, turbines, turbomachinery

For all the analysis to find work done by a compressor or work done on a turbine, the book I'm reading (*Fundamentals of Turbomachinery* by Venkanna B.K) uses the Euler turbine and pump equation, $$W=\dot{m}(V_{w1}U_1\pm V_{w2}U_2) $$ where $V_w$ is the whirl velocity of fluid at inlet and exit, and $U$ is the mean rotational speed of the rotor blades and inlet and exit.
It is based on the conservation of angular momentum of the fluid by drawing velocity triangles.

While this might give the value of work done due to momentum of the fluid, what about the work done by the pressure energy in the fluid or work done to increase the pressure energy of the fluid? Especially in cases like Francis turbine and axial compressors where change in pressure energy plays a big role, how can we consider only the momentum of the fluid in our analysis? I'm guessing work needs to be done to increase the pressure energy as well/work is done by pressure energy in turbines like Francis turbine.

Maybe because of complicated aerofoil shapes of the blades its hard to do an analytical approach but shouldn't we at least account for a factor of change in pressure energy?

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated the book, but as we may not have your book you should show the formula you are looking at.

Comment: I edited my question with both details. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine a derivation of the Euler work equation (http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/SPRING/propulsion/notes/node91.html), you will see that the change in angular momentum of the fluid is proportional to the change in enthalpy of the fluid. Remember the definition of enthalpy is the flow work and the internal energy. Therefore, the enthalpy contains the change in pressure via the flow work term. This is why pressure does not directly appear in the Euler work equation, but is physically accounted for. I recommend stepping through a derivation of the equation yourself to gain a better understanding.

Comment: In the derivation you linked, they substitute the power $P=\omega \dot{m} (v_cr_c-v_br_b)$ in  $P=\dot{w_s}=\dot{m}(h_{T_c}-h_{T_b})$. So they are assuming the total power is $P$ which is obtained from conservation of momentum and equate that to change in enthalpy. So it is only proportional because they assumed it was. My question is how is the total power obtained from considering only change in momentum in cases like Francis reaction turbines where a significant portion of energy comes from converting pressure energy to work?

Comment: Look at the definition of enthalpy. Enthalpy is the sum of the flow work (which includes pressure and density) and the internal energy. Enthalpy includes the pressure in its definition. The enthalpy change and angular momentum are proportional because the power, work, and torque are directly related. This connects conservation of angular momentum to the energy equation, as shown in the link. Power is the work done per unit time. Work is in the energy equation.

Comment: I understand enthalpy includes flow work, but I'm not talking about flow work. As the blades act like airfoils, there will be force acting on the blade due to pressure differences across each side of the blade. This causes work to be done on the blade as a result of pressure difference $between$ two flows. Flow work is the work done to push the fluid into the system so how can it include the work done by the lift forces acting on the airfoil?

Comment: I am an aero engineer, so I understand how it works. Consider flow in a control volume around a turbine rotor airfoil and passage. Flow leaves the CV with less energy than when it entered due to the work done on the airfoil (i.e. the pressure differences between the pressure and suction sides). You can integrate the static pressure distribution on the airfoil surface to obtain the tangential force applied on the airfoil. In an adiabatic flow, the work done on the airfoil by the fluid is reflected in the enthalpy difference between the inlet and exit of the CV. Does this help at all?

Comment: So enthalpy contains the pressure+flow work and the expression given is the shaft work from the impulse force acting on the blades, is that correct? So that means the expression given by the Euler turbine equation is not the total work done on the turbine?

Comment: Yes, the expression given is the work done by the fluid on the blade. However, enthalpy is the summation of the internal energy (U) and the flow work (PV), not the pressure and the flow work. The Euler turbine equation is valid for a single blade row. So, in other words, if the turbine has more than 1 stage, then the equation would need to be applied for each stage. If it is a 4 stage machine, the equation would need to be applied 4 times. Is this more clear?

Comment: I've accepted the answer because I understood the gist of your answer. But I'd like a few clarifications if you don't mind. I get that the enthalpy difference between the inlet and the outlet of the control volume gives the work done by the fluid on the airfoil, like you stated. But in order to find an expression for the work done, is it enough to find the work done by the change in momentum of the fluid (as given in the derivation)? Because that doesn't include the work done by the pressure difference, it's just the impulse work. How is that different from what happens in a pelton turbine?

Comment: It seems like the only difference between the Francis turbine and the Pelton turbine (in terms of analysis of work done) is the velocity triangles of the inlet and outlet flows. Yet the Pelton turbine is known as an impulse turbine and Francis turbine is a reaction-impulse turbine though they both use similar principles to produce work. Where is the extra reaction work the Francis turbine is producing from the change in pressure (is what I meant by saying pressure+flow work)? I can post this as a new question if you'd like. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's enough to find the work via the change in momentum of the fluid. Looking at the link I attached of the Euler turbine equation derivation, the power is used to connect the conservation of energy to the conservation of angular momentum. This directly connects the fluid enthalpy to the velocities. This was derived without regard to reaction (change in pressure) because the enthalpy accounts for the pressure in its def'n. This is why the analysis works for a Francis or Pelton turbine. Is this any more clear? Some differences between water turbines: shorturl.at/tyU15 shorturl.at/uyA15

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear I think I'll study it some more but thanks for your help

Comment: If I may recommend some readings, try Fluid Mechanics and Thermodynamics of Turbomachinery by Dixon and Hall. I think this book lays out the fundamentals quite well. They explain the concepts better than I could myself. If I'm not mistaken, you're having a difficult time understanding how the change in pressure is accounted for with just velocities in the Euler turbine equation, is this correct?

Comment: Yes that was the point I was having trouble with. If I'm not mistaken you're saying the change in enthalpy $dh=Pv$ can be integrated from inlet to outlet to give $\Delta h$ which will account for the work done by pressure to push the blades. That makes sense but shouldn't you include that term in work done? The net power output from the turbine would include the momentum work (as given by the Euler turbine equation) and the pressure work on blades that's accounted for by change in enthalpy.

Comment: I believe I see the confusion. You can determine the power with energy or angular momentum eqns, but be careful not to mix apples and oranges. Energy eqn uses velocity in kinetic energy while ang momentum uses them for torque. The velocity terms in the Euler turbine eqn represent the angular momentum of the fluid entering and leaving the C.V. This is different, but ultimately derived from, the familiar form of the energy eqn, which includes static enthalpy (pressure energy in the incompressible form), kinetic energy, and potential energy. I would describe more but I'm running out of space.

Comment: I've made a chat so we can discuss it more easily instead of one message per day: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110638/turbine-work You've pretty much cleared my original question now its more of a technicality about why the pressure work accounted for by change in enthalpy isn't included when we talk about work done by by a turbine. If you'd like join the chat I'll explain what I mean otherwise thanks for all the help

Comment: I responded in chat. I forgot to turn on notifications so I didn't know you had replied. I'm adding a comment here in case you didn't turn them on either

Comment: notifications don't seem to be working (for me at least)

Comment: they are not working for me either, but i will check regularly